# Starting and Stopping php files using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I can really use some help.  I have 2 php files that run on my LAMP server. php1 connects to a streaming api and gets data based on hash-tags and php2 parses the data and stores it in a mysql database.

I nohup both of these files so they run after I exit my shell.  My goal is to start and stop these files using AJAX from the browser, but I can't figure out how...any suggestions?

tks :)

Comment: Since PHP is server-side, you cannot stop it from running.

Comment: You'll have to create PHP functions that can start and stop the PHP scripts you're using and call those functions with ajax.

Comment: if you store the script pid, you could ungracefully kill it

Comment: is performance important? you can create a 3rd php script that adds a file and simply check if it exists periodically on the other scripts. If it exists, they will stop execuction and remove the file..

Answer (score 0):

I would set some value on a database, the scripts should chcek that value on each run, then your ajax calls should modify that value.

Something like, your script:

```
execute_script = <get_the_value_from_the_db>;
if (excecute_script) {
  //your script code here
}
```

you should leave those files running all the time

then on your ajax calls you set that value from db to true or false

you didn't specify periodicity of the script or any time requirement, i'm just assuming you can leave the script running